# Adduser - home directory set to /

Tags: linux

I added user with adduser user and then entered password with passwd password. When I su - user I got "No directory, logging in with HOME=/"

What's going on, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely the home directory was not created along with the user.  The easiest method would be using usermod:

```
usermod -dm /home/USER USER
```

Where

- -d -- Changes the home directory
- -m -- Creates the home directory if does not exist
- /home/USER -- where this is the full path to the new home directory.

So this does not happen in the future you should always use the ‘create home’ option with useradd:  -m or --create-home.  This will build out the new home directory using /etc/skel as the template.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at /etc/passwd and see what the users home dir is set to, it should be the 6th : seperated column

Use usermod to change his home dir:

```
$ usermod -d /home/user user
```

Comment: You probably meant to say /home/user, not ~/user. The former will point the user's home directory to /home/user, the second to a directory called user *inside the homedirectory of the one who executes the command!*

Comment: Oops, yup you're right. Fixed that :)

Answer (score 1):

It is saying that the directory does not exist, check to make sure that /home/username exists. If it does not then run the following commands

```
mkdir /home/username
cp -r --preserve /etc/skel/* /home/username
chown -R username.username /home/username
```

This should create the directory for the user and stop the error you are seeing from showing up.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your version of adduser doesn't create the new home directory by default?

Answer (score 1):

In future use the `-m` switch to `useradd`:

> -m, --create-home             create home directory for the new user